# How to pass AngularJS checkbox model to $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, get

How can I send an AngularJS checkbox model to the $http.get service successfully?

The standard way of sending an array in get parameters is like so:

```
http://hostname.com/app?keyword=value1&fields[]=checkbox1&fields[]checkbox2
```

Here's the AngularJS checkbox markup I'm using...

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="filters.fields.checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
<input ng-model="filters.fields.checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
```

Here's the controller code that sets up the model and then sends it to $http.get...

XHR:

```
$scope.filters = {
  keyword: '',
  fields:{}
};
$scope.url = 'http://hostname.com/app/';
$http.get($scope.url,$scope.filters).then( ... );
```

This is producing a URL that doesn't match the above standard format:

```
http://hostname.com/app?keyword=test&&fields=%7B%7D
```

Comment: I guess you need to send ,$scope.filters.fields for checkbox list :-P

Comment: Also fields is not an array in your example, but an object.

Comment: Yes I know it is an object. These are both standard angularJS components - checkbox and $httpd. AngularJS requires that the checkbox model be an object, not an array. The question is how to get them to play nice together.